# Make geolocator forget its own history

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, location, mapping

I'm trying to make some very detailed measurements of the current location. I want to see the most subtle differences - inches - between the outputted coordinates on two calls of my method. However, the geolocator seems to remember its last measurement when I hit the "Read Again" button, then just spit out the same coordinates. To confirm this I tried two tests:

In test A, I kept spamming measure again as I was walking. The same measurement was outputted.

In test B, I turned off location services and turned it back on. Then, I made a measurement. I changed my position. Then, I turned it off and back on again and made another measurement. The location changed.

This is my current code for the geolocator.  (It is async and called each time a button is tapped) My goal is to make it forget the last measurement, similar to what happens when I turn location services off.

```
        async void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> locationTask = null;
            try
            {
            if (geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot determine info because location services are turned off.");
            else
            {
                locationTask = geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                Geoposition geoposition = await locationTask;
                distances.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString() + "," + geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString()} );
                updnum = updnum + 1;
                //Numupd.Text = updnum.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (locationTask != null)
            {
                if (locationTask.Status == AsyncStatus.Started)
                {
                    locationTask.Cancel();
                }
                locationTask.Close();

            }
        }
            //locationTask.Cancel();
            return;
            //locationTask.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Try subscribing to the `PositionChanged` and setting the `ReportInterval`, `MovementThreshold`, and `DesiredAccuracyInMeters` and see if the event gets fire on your device.  On my device, it isn't that accurate, it will fire every meter or so from its last position.